# Why does my fresh Klocwork 9.2 installation display a blank Product Portal web page?

Tags: klocwork

I installed Klocwork 9.2.1.7276 on a fresh Windows Server 2008 x86 system. During the installation, I selected all Klocwork components to be installed (database server, licence server, Klocwork server) and ensured that all three servers were running in the Klocwork Management Console. I ran `kwauthconfig` and set the authentication scheme to None.

However, when I attempt to visit the Klocwork Product Portal (Start > Programs > Klocwork 9.2 > Klocwork Product Portal), Internet Explorer opens and displays a blank web page served from port 8080 on the local machine (`http://klocwork:8080`). If I change the URL to `http://klocwork:8080/portal/Portal`, I get the expected page. However, when I click on the links to Klocwork Review (`http://klocwork:8080/review`) or Klocwork Inspect (`http://klocwork:8080/codereview`), I get similarly blank web pages.

My production server (installed years ago by someone who has since left the company) performs as expected, but I need to move it from Windows XP to Windows Server 2008. I have read through the Klocwork 9.2 documentation, and don't think I've missed any configuration steps. This is the third time I have attempted this installation on a clean machine, each time with the same result. On one of these occasions, I ran a Klocwork build (using `kwinject`, `kwadmin`, `kwbuildproject`, and `kwadmin load`) but was not able to view the build because KW Review and Inspect don't work.

Does anyone know how to get a fresh install of Klocwork 9.2 in a state where Review and Inspect will function? Thanks in advance to anyone who can offer some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this problem turned out to be a combination of Windows Server 2008's *Windows Firewall* and *Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration (IE-ESC)* -- both of which are enabled by default in Windows 2008, and neither of which I disabled before installing Klocwork.

Disabling the Windows Firewall and IE-ESC *after* Klocwork was installed did not fix the problem.

However, I reverted the machine to a snapshot taken *just before* I originally installed Klocwork, disabled both Windows Firewall and IE-ESC, installed Klocwork, turned off authentication with `kwauthconfig`, and now the Klocwork Review and Klocwork Inspect login screens load as expected (and `http://klocwork:8080` now redirects to `http://klocwork:8080/portal/Portal`).